# How can I POST data to a website using the PurePDF library?

Tags: apache-flex, alivepdf

I'm evaluating the differences between the purePDF and alivePDF libraries in flex, and I'm setting up some IO code so that I can save documents from either from a web based flex application.

AlivePDF gives a very convenient save() function that sends the data to a web service, which can simply bounce it back using Content-Disposition: Attatchment, but PurePDF has no such feature. How can I send the PDF data from purePDF to a webservice in a similar way?

Comment: Rip the code out of alivePDF and implement w/ the purePDF library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to create a byte array before creating the PdfWriter, pass that into the writer when you create it, and read the document off of the writer.

```
        var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray()
        var writer:PdfWriter = PdfWriter.create(bytes, PageSize.A10);
        var printPage:PdfDocument = writer.pdfDocument;
        var rect:RectangleElement = new RectangleElement(1, 10, 10, 1);
        rect.backgroundColor = new RGBColor(255, 0, 0);
        printPage.open();
        printPage.add(rect);
        printPage.close();

        var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://someserver.com/someservice");
        urlRequest.method = "POST";
        urlRequest.data = bytes;
        navigateToURL(urlRequest);
```